# Html Form sends string instead of an array

Tags: html, forms

I can not send an array to the server through an html form with method post, when the amount of selected checkboxes is only one. In any other case, where the amount of the elements is more than one, it works fine and the form sends me an array with these elements (strings). So the problem is that when the user selects only one element the form sends a string instead of an array with one string. How can i fix that, in order to send me an array with one element(string)?

Yes you are right, i have to provide my code which by the way is in bootstrap 4.0

```
<form method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="myVariable">Choose :</label>
    <div class="form-check">
      <div>
        <input class="form-check-input" name="myVariable" id="idOfChoice1" type="checkbox" value="valueOfChoice1" >
        <label class="form-check-label">
          choice1
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input class="form-check-input" name="myVariable" id="idOfChoice2" type="checkbox" value="valueOfChoice2" >
        <label class="form-check-label">
          choice2
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id="sendDataToServer" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

So, on the above code if i choose both of the checkboxes i get an array with two strings on the server side, which by the way is in expressjs. When i check only one checkbox then instead of an array, i get a string and not an array with a string.
Thank you.

Comment: Provide your code

Comment: Ok, now you can see my code!

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you would just call it as `$form_input=$array[0]`. 
If that's not what you were looking for, please give us some code samples and tell us which programming language you are using so we can (better) help you.